# Altering external variable from Google Maps' StreetViewService.getPanorama({},callback) method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I am running into trouble with this piece of code since I'm not sure how to fix it. I already asked this in the chats but couldn't figure out myself after some answers.
I want to get Panorama from StreetViewService using the method from the Google Maps javascript API from a StreetViewService getPanorama() method.
The method receives a literal with the coordinates and a radius, and a callback function that receives 2 parameters: data and status.
in that callback you check wether the service returns some images for street view or not, in which case you do one thing or another.

It seems the callback is executed asynchronously or the getPanorama method, executing some kind of ajax behind the scenes.

I'm pasting the code below, but first I explain my intentions. I need to return from one method I made inside a literal that is inside a self made library wether the the request has valid images for that requested coordinates or not by setting a variable to true or false and then at the end returning that value. However, even if I set the variable to true inside that callback anonymous function, when the variable returns, it always has it's initial value without it not being changed.

Here the code. Not everything, just the essential code.
Then my intention is to used the boolean returned to know if I have to switch one button active for some kind of job or not or do some things or not depending of if it returned true or false, Change some style etc as well.
I'd appreciate if you could change my code in a way it could be done. I was told about a callback solution or wrapping it into a promise. However I don't know how to do it. I used promisses in jquery but not in vanilla javascript. I'd like to see how the callback solution could be made as well with this code.

```
//Library not show for shortenning the example.
streetView: { //This is inside a library
  valid_request: false,
  event_key: null,
  panorama: null,

  setStreetView: function(coords, element) {
    libMapa.streetView.valid_request = false; // Initialize the value again.

    let sv_service = new google.maps.StreetViewService();
    var latlng = coords;

    sv_service.getPanorama({ // This is a method from Google Map Javascript API.
      location: latlng,
      radius: 50
    }, function(data, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {

        if (!libMapa.streetView.panorama) {
          libMapa.streetView.panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(element);
          libMapa.streetView.panorama.setEnableCloseButton(true);
        }
        libMapa.streetView.panorama.setPano(null);
        libMapa.streetView.panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
        libMapa.streetView.panorama.setVisible(true);

        libMapa.streetView.valid_request = true;

      } else {
        alert("No images for this place");
        // Otherwise variable stays as FALSE.
      }
    });
    return libMapa.streetView.valid_request;
  }
}

/****************************************/
//OUTSIDE THE LIBRARY IN INDEX.HTML

var sv_valid = libMapa.streetView.setStreetView(coords, div_mapa);
//sv_valid still shows false even if it should return true.
if (sv_valid) {
  // "pressed" is to control a button as if it was a switch by activatinc and deactivating it.
  pressed = false; // It always ends up being false even when it should return true.
  element.style.cursor = "default";
  libMapa.mapa.unByKey(libMapa.streetView.event_key);
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit unsure of what your problem is. You should more clearly explain the behavior you expect to happen, what is *actually* happening, any errors you're seeing, and what solutions you've already tried to apply to the problem. That said, it seems you're running into problems understanding the AJAX and managing asynchronous events. Right away I see that you're returning `libMapa.streetView.valid_request;` in a way that will always cause it to be `false`. The callback for `getPanorama` won't run until some time in the future *after* you return the `setStreetView` function.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to stick whatever code you want to happen once you know the result of the panorama being valid or not inside the callback function. Don't return from the setStreetView function because AJAX flow doesn't work that way. Instead just set the value of `streetView.valid_request` appropriately and run whatever code you need to set the button state at the same time (in the callback).

Comment: @JCD However I must access a variable that is not in the library and I cannot pass it and modify it, unless I could do some kind of passing by reference with an object and then retrieve the new value from that object. I mean, could I wrap the variable into a literal object, modify the value and get the value? Would it be modified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a callback to do some action or modify some variable after the AJAX call to `getPanorama()` (and by proxy, `setStreetView()`) is complete.

Modify `setStreetView()` to accept a callback parameter and pass it along to `getPanorama()`.

```
streetView {

    // streetView variables etc.

    setStreetView: function(coords, element, callback) {

        // get ready for the AJAX call etc.

        sv_service.getPanorama({
            // parameter object
        }, function(data, status){
            // The getPanorama() callback.
            // Do stuff with the data/status here,
            // then call the callback function that you passed in to setStreetView.
            // You can send data along (e.g. the result of the AJAX call) to the callback.
            callback(someResult);
        });
    }
}

// somewhere else, where you're calling streetView.setStreetView()
var someVar = "foo";
streetView.setStreetView(someCoords, someElement, function(eventualResult){
    someVar = eventualResult;
});
```

Here's a small example: https://jsfiddle.net/_jered/pgftxgf3/

I also highly suggest you do some research on AJAX, asynchronous JavaScript, and callbacks.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I got it!. I got a negative voting but I don't care. I guess that is because it already existed a similar question. But I think that even if 2 people can have very similar questions, the situation may not be fully 100% the same and sometimes you need a more especific answer or different one, or differently explained one or something. Your answer worked fine and made me realize that even when I thought I knew how callbacks worked, that I didn't in reallity know how they work. Thanks ;-)